# Does my use of Dictionary require locking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking

Many threads have access to `summary`. Each thread will have an unique key for accessing the dictionary;

```
Dictionary<string, List<Result>> summary;
```

Do I need locking for following operations?

1. `summary[key] = new List<Result>()`
2. `summary[key].Add(new Result());`

It seems that I don't need locking because each thread will access dictionary with different key, but won't the **(1)** be problematic because of adding concurrently new record to dictionary with other treads?

Comment: Either can modify the dictionary as a whole (i.e., whatever data structure it's using to hold the data) therefore locking is needed. Just for example, in a hash table the keys might collide; in a tree, both might try to rotate the same subtree. IOW, yes, unless the Dictionary in question specifically supports concurrent access, you need locking.

Comment: @Jerry, what distinguishes your "comment" from an answer?

Comment: @KirkWoll: my lack of certainty about how .NET defines its Dictionary class. Also the fact that it's short enough to fit in a comment. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to use locking.

Dictionary is not thread safe for add operations. 
If you are on .NET 4 you may consider switching to [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). Otherwise you should create your own thread safe collection (such as [this](http://sanjayakumar.blogspot.ro/2009/01/thread-safe-dictionary-in-c.html)).

Consider using a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) for synchronizing access to your collection (in case you won't use ConcurrentDictionary).

Comment: +1, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` works great, and is also found in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @the coon, sorry but I forget to ask: I use now `ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<Result>>`, but do I need also replace `List<Result>` to `BlockingColleciton<Result>` and use `ConcurrentDictionary<string, BlockingColleciton<Result>>`?

Comment: No, if you don't keep references to the Lists somewhere else in your app. If you read/write to the lists through the dictionary (e.g. dict[key].Add(someValue), then it's safe, as the dictionary will ensure thread safe access to the list.

Comment: @the coon, you mean if I use it like this: `var list = new List<Result>; var dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<Result>>(); dic[key] = list;`, so I do need `BlockingColleciton<Result>`instead of `List<Result>`, right?

Comment: You can do directly dic[key] = new List<Results>() and you won't need locking on the list. So you can continue using List<Result>.

Comment: Any problems with it? You should see right away if it works, when testing with 2 or more threads.

Comment: @the coon, if I need to pass the list to method I should use `foo(dic[key].ToList())` (so it will create new list) instead of `foo(dic[key])` and it will be thread safe, right?

Comment: You should use foo(dic[key].AsReadOnly()), so you can make sure the function doesn't modify it. The parameter of the function should be a ReadOnlyCollection<Result>. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx

Comment: @the coon, I don't understand how ConcurrentDictionary prevent from collision when doing dic[key].ToList(). As I understand dic[key].ToList() is equivalent to var l = dic[key]; return l.Tolist();, so once dic[key] returned the list and it is prccessed by ToList new ellements can be added to dic[key] by other thread. What I miss here?

Comment: No, I was busy. In this case, reading your last comment, you need a BlockingCollection. I got confused by the way you were trying to use it, but indeed, you should use it.

Comment: @thecoon, so am I right that `dic[key].AsReadOnly()` or `dic[key].ToList()` is actually equivalent to `var l = dic[key]; return l.Tolist();` and therefore we can get collision between `dic[key]` and `.ToList()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

All write accesses to your dictionnary *must* be locked. There is no guarantee that accessing different keys is thread safe, and, in fact, it isn't.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

By default Dictionary is not thread safe. It does not matter what are you going to add. And the most important: you cannot control concurrent additions from different threads. So you need locks for sure. Or switch to a thread safe collection (i.e. CocnurrentDictionary for .NET 4+)